# PL/SQL using fetching data in LOOPING

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Table :
1.)Test
2.)Position

First table

```
 //TEST
A#
---------------
1
2
3
```

Second table:

```
//Position
A#       POSITION
------------------
1           GM
1         DIRECTOR
2          DOCTOR
3          HELLO
3           GM
```

when i use the following pl/sql in my sqlplus

```
DECLARE
   c_a# test.A#%TYPE;
   c_pos position.position%TYPE;
   CURSOR c_app IS
       SELECT t.a#,p.position from test t
       INNER JOIN position p ON t.a#=p.p#;
BEGIN
   OPEN c_app
   LOOP
       FETCH c_app into c_a# , c_pos;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( c_a# || ':' || c_pos );
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c_app;
END;
/
```

here is the output:

```
1:GM
1:Director
2:Doctor
...
...
```

Expected output:

```
1:GM,Director
2:Doctor
3:HELLO,GM
```

is there anything wrong in my looping?

Comment: this is not related to my question

Comment: This can be doen without using cursors. Do you really need to use cursors?

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: 11g
@arnab. not really need cursor. any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which environment you're using because Oracle have different string aggregation function for `10G` and `11G` release.

For 10G you should consider using `WM_CONCAT` function. Below is the sample code which you're trying to achieve through `cursor`

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR C_APP
   IS
      SELECT   T.A#, WM_CONCAT (P.POSITION)
          FROM TEST T INNER JOIN POSITION P ON T.A# = P.P#
      GROUP BY T.A#;

   C_A#    TEST.A#%TYPE;
   C_POS   POSITION.POSITION%TYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN C_APP;

   LOOP
      FETCH C_APP
       INTO C_A#, C_POS;
      EXIT WHEN C_APP%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (C_A# || ':' || C_POS);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE C_APP;
END;
```

For `11G` you can use `listagg` function. Below is the sample code

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR C_APP
   IS
      SELECT T.A#,
          LISTAGG(P.POSITION,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY P.POSITION) 
     FROM TEST T INNER JOIN POSITION P ON T.A# = P.P#
   GROUP BY T.A#;

   C_A#    TEST.A#%TYPE;
   C_POS   POSITION.POSITION%TYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN C_APP;

   LOOP
      FETCH C_APP
       INTO C_A#, C_POS;
      EXIT WHEN C_APP%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (C_A# || ':' || C_POS);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE C_APP;
END;
```

Make sure you have `set serveroutput on` in order to display the result.

Comment: always face the problem numeric value too small ORA-06502

Comment: it stated line 11 . so any solution ?

Comment: @user3664490 I'm not sure what your table definition looks like. Most probably it's coz of your `Position` column datatype `varchar` range exceeding the limit after returning multiple value for `A#` column. Otherwise I can't seem to think of any other reason why the above code isn't working

Answer (score 1):

You can try one thing. use collect function. It will fetch the details as well as print it in the needed format.

Answer (score 0):

for 11g you can use

```
CURSOR c_app IS
       SELECT t.a#, listagg(p.position, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(order by t.a#) over(partition by t.a#) from test t
       INNER JOIN position p ON t.a#=p.p#;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but , dont you have to close this line?

```
OPEN c_app;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. [DBMS_OUTPUT](http://oreilly.com/catalog/oraclebip/chapter/ch06.html) might help you